# Figure overlaps Table

Tags: tables, spacing, graphics, floats, two-column

When placing a table then a figure, the figure overlaps half the table..
Here is what the tex looks like:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{lR{2cm}R{2cm}R{2cm}R{2cm}R{1.5cm}R{2cm}l}
Name & Value1 & Value2 & Value3 & Value4 & Value5 & Value6 \\
\hline\\
\hspace{5mm}Name1 & 100 & 900 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 47 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\pagebreak
wew

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{chart.png}
    \caption{label1}
    \label{chart}
\end{figure}
```

I am using a two-column style in `\documentclass{sig-alternate}` (academic paper). The actual overlapping is odd, it seems like the figure starts halfway through the table **and** in the second column... So it runs of the page as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`

Comment: create a complete example. That code snippet can't give such a problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide some information as to where one might obtain the file `sig-alternate.cls`; it doesn't seem to be on the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network (CTAN). At any rate, you seem to be requiring that the `tabular` environment be more than 11.5 cm wide; that's going to make it impossible to fit in a single column of a two-column document -- unless your document's paper size is something like A3 or A2... Furthermore, you should probably use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` to specify the width of the graphics object that is to be inserted in the `figure`.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried `\linewidth` and it just made the chart image smaller. `sig-alternate.cls` can be found [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates#aL2).

Comment: Your `tabular` environment has absolutely no chance of fitting in the width of a column. Use the `table*` environment instead of the `table` environment -- doing so will have it span both columns instead of just one or the other. And, if you really want the graphic file to be as wide as `\textwidth` (rather than `\columnwidth`), use a `figure*` environment.

Comment: @Ubobo you need to provide a _complete_ document that shows the problem but don't (ever) just use `[h]` on its own as it makes it hard to place the table and your table is 11.5cm plus the width of the first and last (`l`) columns plus the column padding (16\tabcolsep) does that _really_ fit in one column??

Comment: @Mico thanks, `table*` did the trick :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sig-alternate` class is set up to produce two-column documents. Given that (a) your table is quite a bit wider than a single column and (b) the figure is supposed to be as wide as `\textwidth` (rather than as wide as `\columnwidth`,say), you need to use the environments `table*` and `figure*` to create *full-width (two columns wide) floats*.

By the way, in a two-column LaTeX document full-width floats can only appear at the *top* of a page. Specifying location directives such as `[h]` will not affect the placement of `table*` and `figure*` floats.

The following example shows the top of page 2 of the document that's produced by an augmented form of the code you provided.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit in the production version of your document
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{array,caption,lipsum} % lipsum for filler text
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\
  \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A table} \label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{lR{2cm}R{2cm}R{2cm}R{2cm}R{1.5cm}R{2cm}}
Name & Value1 & Value2 & Value3 & Value4 & Value5 & Value6 \\
\hline\\
\hspace{5mm}Name1 & 100 & 900 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 47 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[1-7] % filler text

\begin{figure*}
%\centering %% no point in trying to "center" a full-width graph...
    \caption{A figure} \label{chart}    
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{chart.png}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[8-30] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it was very helpful. Just one last thing, if I add a `caption` to the `table*`, the whole table becomes centered on the page (vertically) and following elements start on the next page. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Ubobo - Are you maybe also providing a location specifier such as `[p]` when setting up the float in question? The reason I ask is that, as the example I provided in the answer demonstrates, it's *not* the default behavior to typeset a double-wide float on a page by itself. How tall is the float, incidentally? Is it more than half the height of the text block?

Comment: Not specifying `[p]` when setting up the float. With the caption it's about half the page.

Comment: @Ubobo - Your observations that (a) the float in question occupies about half the height of the text block and (b) the problem of the float being placed on a floats-only page arises when you add a caption to the float (thereby increasing the float's total height a bit) are very helpful. You could try resetting the parameters `\dblfloatpagefraction` and `\dbltopfraction` (default value for both: `0.5`). Try executing the commands `\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.8}` and `\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.8}` in the preamble and see if this fixes the layout issue.

Comment: That was it!! Completely fixed the problem. Thanks Mico!