# A figure spanning two columns overlaps with text

Tags: tables, floats

In a two column template, I am trying to include a figure and a table that span both columns. Normally, the commands \begin{figure*} and \begin{table*} should work but in this case, although the figure does span two columns, the second column contains also text which overlaps with the figure. How to make sure that text flows around the figure and does not overlap?

Comment: Could you a small compilable code that shows the problem?

Comment: You are asking people to debug code that you have not shown or even described. No answer is possible unless you give at least some clues

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162688/197451  This should be your solution--two column and figure overlap addressed